# How to know which request a FB Graph's response respond to?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I make a call to FB graph api using FB IOS and handle the response in a delegate object which conforms to FBRequestDelegate. The handle functions is

```
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result;
```

My question is that how do I know which request this response respond to if two requests with same graph path are made?

Look into FBRequest

```
@interface FBRequest : NSObject {
    id<FBRequestDelegate> _delegate;
    NSString*             _url;
    NSString*             _httpMethod;
    NSMutableDictionary*  _params;
    NSURLConnection*      _connection;
    NSMutableData*        _responseText;
    FBRequestState        _state;
    NSError*              _error;
    BOOL                  _sessionDidExpire;
}
```

is there any of these instance variable can be used to distinguish between requests with same graph path?

Thanks

Comment: This method responds whenever you it needs.You have to change the values from "result" array into your own array dynamically to use that values.

Comment: you probably misunderstood my question, what i'm asking here is that if i send two requests (e.g using requestWithGraphPath: andDelegate:) with a same grapPath, how do I know which request the response responds to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can check the request url ..  im currently dealing with it like this .. for example

```
 if([request.url rangeOfString:@"me/feed"].location !=NSNotFound)
{
   //Do something
}
else if([request.url rangeOfString:@"fql.query"].location !=NSNotFound)
{
   //Do something
}
```

Comment: thanks! in case that there are two "me/feed" request sent, is there any way to know distinguish those two requests?

Comment: Yes when you send the parameters (message,accesstoken..etc) you can add a custom parameter to the dictionary so then when you receive the response you can check the parameters also by check request._params.